# Pass a List to Javascript function in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have seen several examples of sending individual parameters to a JavaScript function, but not a List.

When I try to pass a list, it comes to function as a big string. This is what I have:

```
<select id="namespace" name="namespace"
        th:responseList="${responseList}"
        th:onchange="javascript:print(this.getAttribute('responseList'));">
        <option value="">Select Source Namespace</option>
        <option th:each="item : ${responseList}"
            th:value="${item.namespace}"
            th:text="${item.namespace}"></option>
</select>

function print(responseList) {
    console.log(responseList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var list = [[${responseList}]]; 
    console.log(list );
</script>
```

Hope work for you